# Prevent server from interpreting uploaded files

Tags: python, django

I have a `FileField` where the user is meant to upload an image or video for their post: `image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)`

Is there any measure I need to take to prevent users from uploading hostile files? Such as .php files? Or does Django's security already prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageField` instead of `FileField` which will do the validation.

Additionally you can use `FileExtensionValidator` to allow files of particular extensions only ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#fileextensionvalidator)). Django version `1.11` or above is required for `FileExtensionValidator`. But since extension validation won't be enough, you can use `magic` package to check for mime type. ([github](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic))